# Showing Error "argument is not defined" while adding multiple arguments in arrow function but It's Working in Normal Function call

Tags: javascript, function, compiler-errors, arrow-functions

//Example - 1

function  add1(){

```
    if (arguments.length == 0){

        document.write("NO Argument Passed!");
    }
    else{

        let sum = 0;

        for(let num in arguments){

            sum += arguments[num];
        }

        document.write(sum);
    }
}

add1(5,10);
```

In this example, I am getting the correct result.

//Example - 2 ( With Arrow Function)

let sum = () => {

```
    if( arguments.length == 0){

        document.write("NO Argument Passed!");
    }
    else{

        let sum1 = 0;

        for(let number in arguments){

            sum1 += arguments[number];
        }

        document.write(sum1);
    }


};

sum(10,20);
```

*Here I am getting an error in console "arguments is not defined". Please tell me where I did Wrong.Thank you..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because arrow functions [do not have argument bindings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#no_binding_of_arguments).

**option 1** changing arrow function to take an array `arguments` parameter

```js
let sum = (arguments) => {
    if( arguments.length == 0){
        console.log("NO Argument Passed!");
    }
    else{

        let sum1 = 0;

        for(let number in arguments){

            sum1 += arguments[number];
        }

        console.log(sum1);
    }
};
sum([10,20]);
```

**option 2** [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) which allows indefinite amount of arguments

```js
let sum = (...arguments) => {
    if( arguments.length == 0){

        console.log("NO Argument Passed!");
    }
    else{

        let sum1 = 0;

        for(let number in arguments){

            sum1 += arguments[number];
        }

        console.log(sum1);
    }
};
sum(10,20);
```

Comment: Thank You so much, sir. Now my Problem has Solved.